# File not found in Jupyter

Tags: python, ocr, jupyter, tesseract

I'm just starting out with Python and Jupyter, so I apologize in advance for a possible simple question.

I've installed Tesseract, an OCR, to extract text from images and I'm having issues locating the image. How do I specify the location of the image?
Here's my code below.

```
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image
img = Image.open('539_2272.png')
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract.cmd = 'Desktop/oise_tutorial-master/libraries/tesseract-ocr-3.02.grc.tar.gz'
print(pytesseract.image_to_string(img))
```

and I get:

> Requirement already satisfied: Pillow in
>   /anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site- packages (5.2.0) 
>  twisted 18.7.0
>   requires PyHamcrest>=1.9.0, which is not installed. 
>  You are using pip
>   version 10.0.1, however version 18.1 is available. You should consider
>   upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
>   
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
> FileNotFoundError       Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>         
> 3 pytesseract.**path**
>         
> 4 from PIL import Image
>   
> ----> 5 img = Image.open('539_2272.png')
>        
>  6 pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract.cmd = 'Desktop/oise_tutorial-master/libraries/tesseract-ocr-3.02.grc.tar.gz'
>         
> 7 print(pytesseract.image_to_string(img))
>
> /anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PIL/Image.py in open(fp, mode) 
>   
> 2578     
> 2579     if filename:
>   
> -> 2580         fp = builtins.open(filename, "rb")    
> 2581         exclusive_fp = True    
> 2582
>
> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '539_2272.png'

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: The simplest way will be copy the image to the folder where you run jupyter notebook

Comment: Do you know the absolute path of the .png file? (Ex. `"/Users/Claire/Desktop/539_2272.png"`